# Angular and ui-router state children

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this state:

```
}).state('sport', {
    url: "/:sport",
    templateUrl: '/app/sports/sport.tpl.html',
    controller: 'SportController',
    controllerAs: 'controller'
});
```

and the controller looks like this:

```
.controller('SportController', ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
    var self = this;

    // Object to hold our parameter
    self.slug = $stateParams.sport;
}]);
```

So, what I am trying to do is pass this parameter to another state. Which I have set up like this:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {

    // Set up our state(s)
    $stateProvider.state('sport.designer', {
        url: "/designer",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: '/app/designer/designer.tpl.html',
        controller: 'DesignerController',
        controllerAs: 'controller'
    }).state('sport.designer.team', {
        url: "",
        templateUrl: '/app/designer/team.tpl.html'
    }).state('sport.designer.kit', {
        url: "/kit",
        templateUrl: '/app/designer/kit.tpl.html'
    }).state('sport.designer.design', {
        url: "/design",
        templateUrl: '/app/designer/design.tpl.html'
    }).state('sport.designer.refine', {
        url: "/refine",
        templateUrl: '/app/designer/refine.tpl.html'
    }).state('sport.designer.order', {
        url: "/order",
        templateUrl: '/app/designer/order.tpl.html'
    });
}])
```

and the controller looks like this:

```
.controller('DesignerController', ['$stateParams', 'DesignerService', 'HttpHandler', 'Api', function ($stateParams, service, handler, api) {
    var self = this;
    var slug = $stateParams.sport; // Get our slug

    console.log(slug);
}]);
```

So, there are a couple of issues here.

1. If set up a link like this: **ui-sref="sport.designer.team({ sport: controller.slug })"** then the view doesn't move from the **sport** state.
2. The reason I am using **.team** is because **.designer** is an abstract state and the team state is the default state that loads

Here is my html for the sport state:

```
<a ui-sref="sport.designer.team({ sport: controller.slug })">Test</a>
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: any working fiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working today.
My sport state stayed the same.
I changed the designer states to this:

```
// Set up our state(s)
$stateProvider.state('designer', {
    url: ':sport/designer',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/designer.tpl.html',
    controller: 'DesignerController',
    controllerAs: 'controller'
}).state('designer.team', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/team.tpl.html'
}).state('designer.kit', {
    url: '/kit',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/kit.tpl.html'
}).state('designer.design', {
    url: '/design',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/design.tpl.html'
}).state('designer.refine', {
    url: '/refine',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/refine.tpl.html'
}).state('designer.order', {
    url: '/order',
    templateUrl: '/app/designer/order.tpl.html'
});
```

and then in my sport.tpl.html I set the link up:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>{{ controler.slug }}</h1>
            <p>This will be the sport homepage.</p>
            <p><a ui-sref="designer.team({ sport: controller.slug })">Click to get started</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and that was it. Designer, did not have to be a child of sport.